# how to use params in meteor mongo query with react router

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I cannot get my id parameter to show up in the createContainer block.

```
class Host extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this.props.routeParams.hostId)} //works great
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default createContainer(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('hosts');
    return {
        hosts: Hosts.findOne({_id: this.props.routeParams.hostId}), //returns undefined
    };
}, Host);
```

I want to do a query by id here, but the parameters are only available in the class itself. Not in the create container block.

How do I get my parameter to show up in createContainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope of 'this' might cause a problem. Maybe defining the param outside of the return method might work. Can you give this a try

```
export default createContainer(({routeParams}) => {
    const id = routeParams.hostId;
    Meteor.subscribe('hosts');
    return {
        hosts: Hosts.findOne({_id: id}), 
    };
}, Host);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! The scope of this refers to the Window in this case. I can only access meteor from here but not the react-router or anything.

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment :) Whatever, I edited my original answer. Maybe desconstructing routeParams and passing it might help. You can try this as well?